# How to create installer for WCF service,which is created in Visual Studio 2012(.net framework 4.5)?

Tags: windows, wcf, advanced-installer

1. I need to create installer package for WCF(service) class library,which i created in VS2012 with .net framework 4.5.

2.I try to install the service manually using VS2012 command prompt with the following link, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTPCWrZedKI
Actually it put entry in Window services, when i try to start the service manually i am getting an error like **"The service on local computer started and then stopped,Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.**
I tried to fix those errors by changing to local system account and clearing the evenlog,
but nothing works fine for me.

I tried it using Advance installer by providing the dll file in Services tab,but it fails to start the service getting an error like "Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start the stystem sevices".

Please tell me how can i proceed further?
**I don't need to use third party softwares like wix  for creating installer package.**
**Is there any way to achieve this task. If so please guide me and give me a sample application to achieve this task.**
I am spending more than 10 days for this task..
Awaiting for your repliessss!!!

Regards,
Lokesh.J

Comment: The problem is not with the setup package created in Advanced Installer, but with the service. You need to be able to install and run it manually first, then you can go creating the setup package. In what regards creating WCF services, you can start from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx

Comment: I followed the above link,in that i dont want to proceed with windows application for accessing the WCF service, i want Windows service application, so that my wcf service will put entry in (System)Window Services,then i want to start the service. How can i achieve this . help me..